# How do getName of Table A in table B where table A(id)= table B(id)

Tags: module, magento2, magento2-dev-beta

I have action index in my module.

```
namespace Xanka\Slider\Controller\Adminhtml\Slideshow;

class Index extends \Xanka\Slider\Controller\Adminhtml\Slideshow
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory
     */
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $_coreRegistry = null;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Adminhtml\Product\Builder $productBuilder
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
          \Magento\Backend\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry   
    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    /**
     * Product list page
     *
     * @return \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page
     */
    public function execute()
    {
        /*
        *   get all object and create model
        */
        $model = $this->_objectManager->get("Xanka\Slider\Model\Slideshow")->getCollection();

        /** set doi tuong ra block*/
         $this->_coreRegistry->register('slideshow_index', $model);

        /** @var \Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page $resultPage */
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();

        /**$resultPage->setActiveMenu('Xanka_Slider::xanka_slider'); */
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->prepend(__('Slideshow'));
        return $resultPage;     
    }
}
```

And block

```
<?php
namespace Xanka\Slider\Block\Adminhtml\SlideshowData;

use \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container;
class Index extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Container
{   

    protected $_slideshowDataFactory;
     protected $_coreRegistry = null;

     public function __construct(
         \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Context $context, 
          \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Xanka\Slider\Model\Resource\SlideshowData\CollectionFactory $slideshowDataFactory,     
        array $data =[]     
    )
    {
        $this->_slideshowDataFactory = $slideshowDataFactory;
         $this->_coreRegistry = $registry;
      parent::__construct($context, $data);

    }
     protected function _prepareLayout()
    {              
        return parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

     public function getModel(){
         $models = $this->_coreRegistry->registry('slideshowdata_index');
         return $models;
     }



}
```

So in index.phtml i want getName in table Slideshow()

```
<div class = "grid content admin__data-grid-wrap">
<div class="head"><a href="<?php echo  $this->getUrl('*/*/new')?>">Add new</a></div>
    <table class = "data-grid">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th class = "data-grid-th"><span>ID</span></th>
                <th class = "data-grid-th"><span>Name</span></th>
                <th class = "data-grid-th"><span>Slideshow Name</span></th>
                <th class = "data-grid-th"><span>Image Url</span></th>
                <th class = "data-grid-th"><span>Description</span></th>
                <th class = "data-grid-th"><span>Active All Slide</span></th>
                <th class = "data-grid-th"><span>Created time</span></th>
                <th class = "data-grid-th"><span>Updated time</span></th>
                <th class = "data-grid-th"><span>Action</span></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <?php $models = $this->getModel();  ?>
        <?php if($models -> count() > 0 ): ?>
            <?php foreach($models as $model): ?>
                <?php   $objSlideshow = $this->_objectManager->get("Xanka\Slider\Model\Slideshow")->load($model->getId());?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="a-left"><?php echo $model->getId();  ?></td>
                    <td class="a-left"><?php echo $model->getName(); ?></td>
                    <td class="a-left"><?php echo $objSlideshow ->getName(); ?></td>                
                    <td class="a-left"><?php echo $model->getDescription(); ?></td>
                    <td class="a-left"><?php if($model->getActiveAll() =="1") {echo "Yes";}else{echo "No";}?></td>
                    <td class="a-left"><?php echo $model->getCreated_at(); ?></td>
                    <td class="a-left"><?php echo $model->getUpdated_at(); ?></td>
                    <td class="a-left">                 
                            <select onchange="onchangeAction(this.value);" name="action-grid" id="action-slideshow">
                                <option  selected > Select</option>
                                <option value="<?php echo  $this->getUrl('*/*/edit', ['slideshowdata_id' => $model->getId()]); ?>">Edit</option>
                                <option  value="<?php echo  $this->getUrl('*/*/delete', ['slideshowdata_id' => $model->getId()]); ?>">Delete</option>
                            </select>                   
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php else: ?>
            <?php echo "we can find entity. "?>
        <?php endif; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function onchangeAction(url){
        window.location = url;
    }
</script>
```

So `<?php   $objSlideshow = $this->_objectManager->get("Xanka\Slider\Model\Slideshow")->load($model->getId());?>` what wrong ? . Thanks

Comment: Please add any errors etc that you might be getting. Also make the title of the post clearer so people know what it is about

Comment: $objSlideshow nothing result.

Answer (score 2):

In Magento 2 template has access only to public interface of block. So code 
 `$this->_objectManager`  will not work. Also `$this` in templates it is template engine, not the block. For access to the block instance using `$block` variable.

For me Direct using if Object Manager is bad idea. Use constructor DI for block instead.